# onNavigationItemSelected not functioning?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation-drawer, androidx

I am fairly new to Android programming. I have looked for answers everywhere but I don't think I know the source of this issue. Here's the problem :

I added a Navigation Drawer to my app today, and I have 5 different fragments which I wanna switch between each other. Everything is going smoothly except for the most important thing: Calling something when the navigation drawer buttons are clicked.

For the sake of simplicity, the Navigation Drawer for now only has TWO buttons: Home and About.

Here's my onNavigationItemSelected :

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Home clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        
        R.id.nav_about -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "About clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
    binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

As you can see, the drawer DOES get closed, but no Toast appears. I already added this below OnCreate:

```
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

So I don't know what's exactly happening?! Why is onNavigationItemSelected executing but not the "when" expression?!

There is no error, no warning, no crash, not a single thing. I click on the buttons and nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was right in front of my eyes the whole time, these two don't function well together:

```
        navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

I removed the first line and kept the second, now all transactions of fragments are happening and the onNavigationItemSelected is working flawlessly.

Comment: thanks bro, you saved me, I spent several hours searching for answers and tests.
And your answer was the only correct one